# nginx rewrite: add index.php

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

how do I do a rewrite in nginx from

```
http://www.example.com (with or without trailing slash)
```

to add index.php at the end?

For the example above the result should be

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
```

No special rules, just one domain to change.This should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out :-(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want the user's address bar to change, you just need one extra location in your server block:

```
location = / {
  return 301 http://www.example.com/index.php;
}
```